# How to support multiple SIMD instructions in a single Python application?

Tags: python, c++, gcc, simd, pybind11

**Background**: My C++ source has 2 distinct paths one for SSE4.1 and the other for AVX512F instructions. I use this source as an extension to my Python source where it is imported. I compile the extension with the help of `pybind11` and `CMake` through Python `setuptools` and create a platform wheel. In cmake I define 2 distinct modules one for SSE4.1 instruction-based code and the other for AVX512F-based code.

```
pybind11_add_module(qsim_sse pybind_interface/sse4_1/pybind_main.cpp)
pybind11_add_module(qsim_avx pybind_interface/avx512f/pybind_main.cpp)
```

In Python the modules are used as follows:

```
from qsimcirq import qsim_sse

OR

from qsimcirq import qsim_avx
```

depending on the CPU capabalities. Under the hood the `qsimcirq` package contains `qsim_sse.so` and `qsim_avx.so` compiled extensions.

**Problem**: When I compile C++ source with the following gcc flags `-O0 -mavx512f -fopenmp` on an AVX-capable CPU and try to import **only** `qsim_sse` module on CPU which does **not** support AVX instructions I get `Fatal Python error: Illegal instruction`.

**Question #1**: Why is that the case? `qsim_sse` module does **not** use AVX instruction and was only compiled using `-mavx512f` flag. Does gcc with `-mavx512f` compile code only for AVX-supporting CPUs?

**Question #2**: What is the best practice to provide multi-SIMD instruction support in a single Python application? Compile AVX and SSE4.1 modules separately with different flags?

Comment: -mavx512f means gcc is free to use AVX512F instructions as it sees fit, not just where you used intrinsics. Compiling several translation units with different flags is indeed the most common way.

Comment: If `-mavx` is enabled, GCC will use VEX encodings for every XMM instruction.  (`-mavx` is implied by `-mavx512f`, but normally you should always use `-march=skylake-avx512` to also imply tuning options.  Also of course `-O0` is total garbage, but I guess you're doing that in hopes that GCC won't auto-vectorize anything and introduce AVX-512 instructions when compiling code that doesn't use intrinsics.)